# How long should format /FS:FAT32 take on a 1.5TB drive?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, external-hard-drive, formatting, fat32

I realize formatting of drives can take a large amount of time, but I haven't formatted a drive in literally "forever" (probably not since Windows XP or Windows 2000).

I have a 1.5TB external HDD (connected via USB Type-A 3.1 port on the PC. I am unsure on whether the HDD and the USB cable support USB 3.0/3.1, or only the older USB 2), which I am formatting on windows 10 via the powershell command

```
format /FS:FAT32 D:
```

Here's my full powershell console, and it's been like this for about 2+ hours with no change.

```
PS C:\Users\chris> format /FS:FAT32 D:
The type of the file system is EXFAT.
The new file system is FAT32.
```

I realize this is not a long time in the land of HDD formatting - especially (probably) given the large size of the drive. But from what I remember from the Windows 2000 days (and I may be wrong), while formatting HDDs did take long, there was usually some kind of UI/console update to give a user any sense on what was happening and how long it **might** take.

However, I have no change at all in the console output for mentioned 2+ hours. **Am I right in just leaving the task running? And how long could I reasonably expect before some kind of update in the powershell console?**

Comment: I would be inclined to let it run overnight.  It will likely be done in the morning.

Comment: You really should not use FAT32 on larger drives. It has a 4GB file limit and no journal to aid file recovery. Better to use NTFS.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use NTFS as I want this drive to be natively accessible by MacOS and Unix/Linux as well. Plan is to hook up the drive to my wireless router and use it as a shared drive across multiple OS's. My router can't mount ext2/3/4, which would have been my #1 choice otherwise.

Comment: Anyway, it turns out that there seems to be a loose contact somewhere along the USB-Cable, and this is what caused the format to "grind to a halt". I discovered it when I accidentally moved the USB-Cable ever so slightly, and heard the "bleep" sound on Windows 10 indicating a new drive had been discovered. I now did a quickformat with fat32format which seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Additional point to be made @oldfred: I just discovered that, supposedly, Mac has no issus reading AND writing to NTFS drives natively if they are remote network drives. So I may actually go along the NTFS route. Thanks for pointing me back in that direction!

Comment: @Chris all modern OSes can read/write exFAT without problem. The spec has even been opened by MS

Comment: Actually I tried exFat as well, and my wireless router can't mount it out of the box, unfortunately. I would need to flash it with a new OS, which seems like too much hassle. Thanks for the input though!